# Runtime of 2 Keys Keyboard recursive algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion

Recently I've stumbled upon one of the algorithm which is known as 2 Keys Keyboard. The problem statement is as follows:

Initially on a notepad only one character 'A' is present. You can perform two operations on this notepad for each step:

Copy All: You can copy all the characters present on the notepad (partial copy is not allowed).
Paste: You can paste the characters which are copied last time.

Given a number n. You have to get exactly n 'A' on the notepad by performing the minimum number of steps permitted. Output the minimum number of steps to get n 'A'.

Example 1:

Input: 3
Output: 3
Explanation:
Intitally, we have one character 'A'.
In step 1, we use Copy All operation.
In step 2, we use Paste operation to get 'AA'.
In step 3, we use Paste operation to get 'AAA'.

Note:

The n will be in the range [1, 1000].

Source: Leetcode.com: https://leetcode.com/problems/2-keys-keyboard/

I've come up with a recursive solution which works fine. However I am confused about it's runtime though. Here is my recursive algorithm:

```
class Solution {
public int minSteps(int n) {
    if(n == 1){
        return 0;
    }
    return recursiveDriver(1, 1, n, 1);
}

public int recursiveDriver(int currCount, int totalOperationsSoFar, int target, int previousCopy){
   
    if(currCount == target){
        return totalOperationsSoFar;
    }
    if(currCount > target || previousCopy > target){
         return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
    int countAfterAddingPreviousCopy = currCount+previousCopy;
    int previousCopyVersion = recursiveDriver(countAfterAddingPreviousCopy, totalOperationsSoFar+1, target, previousCopy);
    int pastePreviousAndCopyVersion = recursiveDriver(countAfterAddingPreviousCopy, totalOperationsSoFar+2, target, countAfterAddingPreviousCopy);
    int minNeeded = Integer.min(previousCopyVersion, pastePreviousAndCopyVersion);
    return minNeeded;
}  
}
```

I thought the runtime would be O(2^n) but what would be n in the worst case?

Answer (score 0):

The run-time of your algorithm is `O(n)` because it will find a way to get to each number in the range `1..n` and then makes at most 1 call to a larger number that could be out of range.

There is a `O(log(n))` version.  Think hard about the base 2 representation of `n` to find it.

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity is certainly not *O(n)*, as besides the linear solution consisting of one copy and then all pastes, there are many others (including those that overshoot the target).

I could not really pin it down, but from taking samples it looks very close to *O(n<sup>7/4</sup>)*.

There is however a *O(logn)* solution:

Think of what the solution would be for 17:

There really is no other way than to copy, and then paste 16 times. The reason is that the last paste extension *must* necessarily have a size that is a proper divisor of *n*. And 17 has no other proper divisor than 1. So you can only reach 17 by pasting sizes of 1.

In fact, when you think this through: *all* pastes must be divisors of *n*.

And since we want to maximise the size of what we paste (to get to the target faster), you come to realise that you need to gather all prime divisors of *n*, including potential multiple occurrences of a prime divisor (like 2 divides 8 three times).

When for instance *n* is 45, we have prime divisors 3² and 5. And so the solution is:

copy, paste, paste (to make 3)
copy, paste, paste (to make 3²)
copy, paste, paste, paste, paste (to make 3².5)

Notice how each line has a number of operations that corresponds to the prime factor. And so we need the *sum* of the prime divisors (including duplicates of those).

The final implementation can thus be:

```java
class Solution {
    public int minSteps(int n) {
        // sum prime factors
        int sum = 0;
        int div = 2;
        while (n > 1) {
            while (n % div == 0) {
                n /= div;
                sum += div;
            }
            div++;
        }
        return sum;        
    }
}
```

You could further optimise with so called "wheel factorisation", but for this challenge (limited to *n <= 1000*) that doesn't really give much gain.